# MSBuild target in csproj do a clean before every build

Tags: msbuild, target, csproj

I have a C# project (vs2013) and for this project, i want to do always a clean solution before the build. Now i can (again and again) choose clean project before building, but this should be possible using a Target tag in the .csproj file. I started looking on the internet and came up with a solution that did not work:

```
<Target Name="Clean"
       BeforeTargets="Build">
  <Message Text="### Start Clean before build"
           Importance="high" />
  <Exec Command="CALL &quot;$(MSBuildBinPath)\msbuild.exe&quot; &quot;$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)&quot; /t:Clean" />
  <Message Text="### Finished Clean before build"
           Importance="high" />
</Target>
```

But this results in an infinite loop, starting msbuild over and over again.

Answer (score 2):

You've defined the target recursively. Don't name it "Clean", name it "PreBuildClean" or something similar.

Also you don't have to call out to msbuild externally using Exec. You can use the `CallTarget` task to invoke a target directly.

```
<Target Name="PreBuildClean"
   BeforeTargets="Build">
  <Message Text="### Start Clean before build"
           Importance="high" />
  <CallTarget Targets="Clean" / >
  <Message Text="### Finished Clean before build"
           Importance="high" />
</Target>
```

The Rebuild target is just Clean followed by Build, so I'm not sure why you'd need this, unless it is only for one specific project in the solution.